# Unable to load HTML page

Tags: angularjs

templateUrl is unable to render HTML page,the error is  'page cannot be found'.I have tried using both relative and absolute path.I have a folder "template predictions", in that i have "template-predictions.html","template-predictions.controller.js" , "template-predictions.config.js"

```
`
templateUrl:"template-predictions.html",
`
```

Comment: Could you include your folder structure for clarity please, specifically I'd like to see where your index.html and the file that has that line of code are located.

Comment: I was about to add image, but i dont have 50 reputation... folder structure is src>app>components>template-predictions>--index.js, template-predictions.html, template-predictions.controller.js , template-predictions.config.js. My code is in template-predictions.controller.js.@TomNijs

Comment: Could you try specifying `./template-predictions.html` instead of `template-predictions.html`

Comment: I tried but the other error i am getting is "TypeError: Cannot read property '$scope' of undefined" @TomNijs

Comment: That's a good sign, a new error is progress for us developer! That means it has found your html file successfully and is now trying to compile your controller which has an error - the one you just mentioned. Could you post your controller code?

Comment: yes,But its too big code. Shall i share on stackblitz ?

Comment: I think that merits a new question since your original question has been answered